# Update attributes after using finding objects that meet conditions in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to find object(s) that meets several conditions, and then update the attributes of each object. The problem is that the "where" method doesn't work for this because it returns the result as an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not the object itself, and so `update_attributes` doesn't work.

But I'm confused because Rails 4 wants you to use `where` not `find`, so I don't know how to achieve this. How would you rewrite this code?

```
Invenborrow.where(inventory_id: inventory_id).where.not(borrow_id: borrow_id).update_attributes(status: "Declined")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

```
Invenborrow.where(inventory_id: inventory_id).where.not(borrow_id: borrow_id).update_all(status: "Declined")
```

Comment: ok I'm super confused and annoyed because Where is always retrieving relations... so what if I just wanted to see the `status`? Well, if I type `Invenborrow.where(inventory_id: inventory_id).where.not(borrow_id: borrow_id).status` I get a no method error. Thoughts?? How do I generally get at the object and not the relation?

Comment: You could use pluck. e.g. Post.pluck(:status) 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: You can also loop thru the Relation object with `@data.each ...` then you get access to each item. Or even with array access, `@data[0]`